# How can I mark an index as 'used' when iterating over a list?

Tags: python, space-complexity

I will iterate over a `list of integers, nums,` multiple times, and each time, when an integer has been 'used' for something (doesn't matter what), I want to mark the index as used. So that in future iterations, I do not use this integer again.

Two questions:

1. My idea is to simply create a separate list `marker =  [1]*len(nums)` ; and each time I use a number in nums, I will subtract 1 from the corresponding index in marker as a way to keep track of the numbers in `nums` I have used.
   My first question is, is there a well known efficient way to do this? As I believe this would make the SPACE COMPLEXITY O(n)
2. My other idea is to replace each entry in nums, like this. `nums = [1,2,3,4]`  `->` `nums = [(1,1),(2,1),(3,1),(4,1)]`. And each time I use an integer in nums, I would `subtract 1` from the second index in each pair as a way of marking that it has been used. My question is, am I right in understanding that this would optimise the SPACE COMPLEXITY relative to solution 1. above? And the SPACE COMPLEXITY here would be O(1)?

For reference, I am solving the following question: https://leetcode.com/contest/weekly-contest-256/problems/minimum-number-of-work-sessions-to-finish-the-tasks/

Where each entry in `tasks` needs to be used once.

Comment: Please ask only one question. If you have more questions post it as another question.

Comment: Why would the space complexity be O(1) in the second case? `nums` is a list of tuples, so its total size is `n * 2`, since each tuple holds 2 elements. In the first case, both `marker` and `nums` hold `n` items, so `n * 2` elements as well.

Comment: Please add some code with sample input and expected output so we can see where your problem might be

Comment: Hi PCM, I appreciate that but the two questions are very much related! Should I still separate them?

Comment: Practically speaking, you are still using additional space. It doesn't really matter if you account for it in the input or the algorithm.

Comment: @ForceBru, I see! I thought it would be O(1) since we are simply replacing each entry with a tuple pair, but I see now this logic is wrong.

Comment: @hfddhudfhs It's *technically* O(1) space complexity, but you've just shifted the additional space requirements to whoever builds the input.

Comment: @chepner, just to confirm my understanding- If I perform my algorithm 'in-place' with the given input, then SC is O(1). However, if I create a list, and the length of the list will depend on the length of the  input list, then the SC would be O(n). Is this correct?

Comment: Yes. The space complexity of this particular algorithm is independent of the input size, but you've increased the space complexity of whatever *uses* this algorithm.

Comment: Surely if you are going to keep track of `n` independent things then you need to keep track of `n` things. I don't see how you could possibly do that in less than `O(n)` space. If you could, then you would have a magic way of compressing n bits into something smaller than n bits.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. I don't think there is a way to do it in O(1) space. Although, I believe that using a boolean value instead of an integer value or using the concept of sets would be a better solution.
2. No, the space complexity is still O(n). Think about it like this. Let us assume n is the size of the list. In the first method that you mentioned, we are storing n 'stuff' separately. So, the space complexity is O(n). In the second method also, we are storing n 'stuff' separately. It's just that those n 'stuff' are being stored as part of the same array. So, the space complexity still remains the same which is O(n).

Comment: Thanks Muhammed, this makes perfect sense.

Comment: Please accept the answer if it answered your question.

Comment: Yupp, had to wait a few mins before I could

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, In both cases, the space Complexity comes out to be O(n). This is because nums itself utilizes O(n) space whether or not you use a separate list to store usage of elements. So space complexity in any way cannot come down to O(1).
However, here is a suggestion.
If you don't want to use the used element again then why not just remove it from the list.
Or, in case you don't want to disrupt the indexing, just change the number to -1.

Comment: Thanks Srishti for the suggestion, indeed the first thing that I thought of is simply removing the element, but it becomes messy when iterating over it. Also, would I be right in saying that my suggested solution of creating a 'marker' table is the same as your suggestion of changing the element to -1 after being used? When I say 'the same' I mean the space and time complexity would be the same- is this right?

Comment: If you are maintaining a separate table for storing 0 or -1 it will definitely take more space. However, theoretically, it would take O(n) space complexity.